# SSAS cube stopped showing data for measure in date dimension for recent months

Tags: ssas

New to SSAS but long time database developer. We have a cube that has been working fine for more than a year but data for last month and this month (Nov-Dec 2014) is not showing up for 3 of eight measures. I found the queries for the measures and ran them against the database and the November and December data shows up in the queries. The date dimension includes the months in question.
Why would the data stop showing up for the measures?

Comment: When you built your date dimension, are you sure you created dates for more than the first year? I don't think it does that by default.

Comment: I didn't build the date dimension but I checked that it includes dates out to 2017.